# Google analytics account spam

Tags: spam-prevention, google-analytics

there are tons of entries that are clearly spam

most of the links are from page.link

I blacked out the links so the hacker cannot figure out who I am posting this
[image]

when trying to delete them aka remove my access, I get the message that I am the only administrator and that each thing needs at least one administrator. So I can't even delete them or remove my access

Comment: I would contact Google for assistance.

Comment: since when does google respond to support requests???

Comment: @Toskan- You originally submitted your question on Super User, question about web sites and accounts associated with those accounts, are not within topic. Since I suspect this is a issue unique to your account, I provided you a way forward, instead of just copying and pasting the close vote reason in a comment (to let you know the question wasn't within scope at Super User).

Comment: @Toskan, it might be helpful to post the actual error message you received rather than paraphrasing it.

Comment: The full error message is "Performing this action would remove the last administrator from this account, and accounts must have at least one administrator." It seems the creator of this spam account made the account, added me, and then removed themselves. I'm left without enough permissions to delete the account entirely, but I'm the last admin so I can't remove myself either.